# A div > ul > li menu with overflow does not work

Tags: html, css

However I search, I cannot find a valid example.... 
I have a typical horizontal menu build with a :

```
div  ul     li a    li a  ... /ul / div
```

(li elements has align left)

Overflow hidden applied on div or ul does nothing. I have always a vertical adjust of li elements when I resize the browser to test the overflow behavior

I have played with position, etcs....

Can any "charitable" soul write an example or give a link?
Thanks....

Comment: Question would be easier to understand if you provide some code snippet or fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `div` or `ul` don't have a specified height, they will grow to adjust to their content, and the content will not be treated as overflow.

Comment: Oh, it is true. So, usually it is incompatible have "auto-height" divs and overflow control at the same time... isn`t it ?

Comment: indeed. because the element will simply grow.. without overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you properly `clear: both;` after floating your `li` elements, the `div` and the `ul` will have no height at all.
If you have done that, then it is not very clear what you are trying to hide, with `overflow: hidden;`

One thing is sure: You should figure out **if** the `div` and `ul` have heights and widths, and what those values are, and if they don't, you can manually assign them, to fit your toolbar (for example).

Comment: who said he's floating the `li`s?